# Why do I still get the "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" error at the if-conditional even after defining my arrays as GEKKO params?

Tags: gekko

I am trying to define arrays as GEKKO params, that will be used with comparison operators such as `>`, `<`, `>=`, `!=` and even within other functions outside the ones shown in the code below. How can I handle such without the `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` error?. Running the code as shown below, throws the `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len error`. Any guidance will be hugely appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from gekko import GEKKO

def check_p_u(u_hub_next):
    m = GEKKO(remote=True)
    u_hub_next = m.Param(value = u_hub_next)

    if 0 <= u_hub_next < 3:
        p_u = 0
        return p_u
    elif 3 <= u_hub_next < 3.5:
        p_u = 8
        return p_u
    elif 3.5 <= u_hub_next < 4.5:
        p_u = 10.5
        return p_u    
    else:
        return 0.1

def intpolatn(u_hub_next):
    m = GEKKO(remote=True)    

    u_hub_next = m.Param(value = u_hub_next)    
    windvel = m.Param(np.array([0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
    thrust_coeff = m.Param(np.array([0, 0.88, 0.88, 0.87, 0.87, 0.86, 0.84, 0.79, 0.71, 0.6]))

    f = interpolate.interp1d(windvel, thrust_coeff, kind = 'cubic')

    if windvel[0] <= u_hub_next < windvel[1]:
        m = 0
        c_t = 0
        axial = 0
        p_u = check_p_u(u_hub_next) 
        u_hub_next = 0
        return [u_hub_next, c_t, axial, p_u]

    elif windvel[1] <= u_hub_next < windvel[2]:
        c_t = f(u_hub_next)
        axial = 0.5 * (1 - np.sqrt(1 - c_t))
        p_u = check_p_u(u_hub_next)
        return [u_hub_next, c_t, axial, p_u]

    elif windvel[2] <= u_hub_next < windvel[3]:
        c_t = f(u_hub_next)
        axial = 0.5 * (1 - np.sqrt(1 - c_t))
        p_u = check_p_u(u_hub_next)
        return [u_hub_next, c_t, axial, p_u]

    elif windvel[3] <= u_hub_next < windvel[4]:
        c_t = f(u_hub_next)
        axial = 0.5 * (1 - np.sqrt(1 - c_t))
        p_u = check_p_u(u_hub_next)
        return [u_hub_next, c_t, axial, p_u]


y = intpolatn(3.2)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Gekko calls the function only once when building the model. The model is compiled with the function call `m.solve()` and the problem is given to a solver to find a solution. To use `if` statements in a model, use either the MPCC form with `m.if2()` or the mixed integer form with `m.if3()` (preferred). [Here](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions) is additional help on logical conditions in optimization problems.

Because Gekko also needs to compile the model for automatic differentiation, some functions are not supported (such as `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`). Use the Gekko `m.cspline()` function instead. Below is an example.

[image: Cubic Spline]

```py
from gekko import gekko 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""
minimize y
s.t.     y = f(x)

using cubic spline with random sampling of data
"""

# Function to generate data for cspline
def f(x):
    return 3*np.sin(x) - (x-3) 

# Create model
c = gekko()

# Cubic spline
x = c.Var(value=15)
y = c.Var()
x_data = np.random.rand(50)*10+10
y_data = f(x_data)
c.cspline(x,y,x_data,y_data,True)
c.Obj(y)

# Options
c.options.IMODE = 3
c.options.CSV_READ = 0
c.options.SOLVER = 3
c.solve()

# Generate continuous trend for plot
z = np.linspace(10,20,100)

# Check if solved successfully
if c.options.SOLVESTATUS == 1:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(z,f(z),'r-',label='original')
    plt.scatter(x_data,y_data,5,'b',label='data')
    plt.scatter(x.value,y.value,200,'k','x',label='minimum')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
else:
    print ('Failed to converge!')
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(z,f(z),'r-',label='original')
    plt.scatter(x_data,y_data,5,'b')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```